# gsutil in Python throws Syntax error

Tags: python, shell, syntax-error, gsutil

Share python script which uses `gsutil` to download a file from google cloud storage bucket.  I am facing an issue while using `gsutil` Python scripts throws

Syntax error : Invalid Syntax

[image]

Comment: Please do not include images of text. Copy and paste the text in your answer, formatting it accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

That syntax error occurs because that command is supposed to be run from the command line and not the Python interpreter itself.

If you search for `cmd` or  `PowerShell` and try it in that shell instead, it should work - I am guessing you are on Windows from the direction of slashes, but it will be called `terminal` on Linux and Mac.

If you want to execute it from a Python script you could use `subprocess` or `os.system()`.

With `os.system()`:

```
os.system('gsutil cp gs:\\somepath C:\\Users\\sensekar\\Desktop\\Python\\')
```

With `subprocess`:

```
subprocess.Popen('gsutil cp gs:\\somepath C:\\Users\\sensekar\\Desktop\\Python\\', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Note that using `subprocess` is better practice.

Remeber also to use `\\` and not escape character `\`.

Comment: Thanks. When i try to do that It throws an error message.  
   C:\gsutil>C:\Python27\python.exe C:\Users\sensekar\Desktop\Python\GCSCopyfile.py
There is no argcomplete library under the gsutil third-party directory (C:\Python27\lib\third_party).
The gsutil command cannot work properly when installed this way.
Please re-install gsutil per the installation instructions.

Comment: @SenthilSekar  The docs suggest `python` as a prefix to `gsutil`, does that fix the problem?  So `python gsutil cp gs:\\somepath C:\\Users\\sensekar\\Desktop\\Python`  
 Source: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/quickstart-gsutil